# How to apply a nuke password for cryptsetup LUKS ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: password, encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I have problem to setup nuke password, in either ubuntu 18.04, or ubuntu 20.04
i think last version of cryptsetup patch failed to be applied in ubuntu
https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/cryptsetup-nuke-password

can't we for example temporary use kali repository and install using apt-get:
apt install cryptsetup-nuke-password

would u help me solve this?

Comment: Hi and welcome. There are not Ubuntu versions of 18 or 20. Please correct with the actual version.

Comment: Also "not working" is not really helpful error description.